# Pandas dataframe if else condition based on previous rows not working

Tags: python

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,1,1, 0, 0]})
df

    X
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   0
4   0
```

Now I want to modify X based on the below condition:

If X = 0 , previous row + 1
So, my final output should look like below:

```
    X
0   1   
1   1 
2   1
3   2
4   3
```

This can be achieved by iterating over rows and setting up a current and previous row and using iloc and is working as expected

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    current_row = df.iloc[i]
    if i > 0:
        previous_row =df.iloc[i-1]
    else:
        previous_row = current_row
    if (current_row['X'] == 0):
        current_row['X']  = previous_row['X'] +1
```

I want more efficient way of doing that and I tried the below code but the output is not what I expected (the value of X for 5th row should be 3):

```
conditions = [df["X"] == 0]
values = [df["X"] .shift() + 1]
df['X'] = np.select(conditions, values)

>>> df
     X
0  1
1  1
2  1
3  2
4  1
```

Comment: It is giving me the same result

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]})

# values previous to zero
pe_zero = df.X.shift(-1).eq(0) * df.X  # [0 0 1 0 0]

# 1 for reach zero value as you sum one to the previous value
eq_zero = df.X.eq(0)

# find consecutive groups of 0
groups = pe_zero + eq_zero
consecutive = (groups.gt(0) != groups.gt(0).shift()).cumsum()

# find cumulative sum by groups
cumulative = groups.groupby(consecutive).cumsum()

# choose from cumulative when equals to zero else from original
result = np.where(eq_zero, cumulative, df.X)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1 1 1 2 3]
```

**UPDATE**

For `df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]})`
returns:

```
[1 1 1 2 3 1 1 2 3]
```

Comment: But this doesnot work if I have a dataframe like this :  df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,1,1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]})

Comment: @Shanoo Updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
arr = df.X.values # extract the column as a numpy array for faster iteration
for i, val in enumerate(arr[1:], start=1):
    if val == 0:
        arr[i] = arr[i-1] + 1
```